# I'm Building an Indicator by Converting from Excel to Pine Script , But Faced a Problem

Tags: pine-script

I'm developing and indicator by modifying VWAP.

The formula is below :

```
PriceDis = (close-(high+low)/2) * (close-(high+low)/2)

NewVolume = PriceDis * volume
```

***Then , I need to find the Total New Volume for 200 days by cumulating 200 days (This is the problem , I dont know how to cumulate it via Pine Script)

```
WeightedVolume = New Volume / Total New Volume (cumulated for 200days)

WeightedPrice = weighted volume * close

plot(Weighted Price)

///// Below Is My Code

**//@version=4
study("籌碼平均線 by Jason")

PriceDis = (close-(high+low)/2) * (close-(high+low)/2)

NewVol = PriceDis * volume

TotalNewVol = 0
for i = 0 to 3
    TotalNewVol := TotalNewVol + int(NewVol[i])

WeightedVol = NewVol / TotalNewVol

WeightedPrice = close * WeightedVol

plot(WeightedPrice)

/////
```

I take the latest 4 days of VOO as an example.

**My Excel result is :**

1st Day Weighted Price = 163.4566955

2nd Day Weighted Price = 103.2890662

3rd Day Weighted Price = 98.76703029

4th Day Weighted Price = 54.92585925

**Pine Script Result :**

1st Day Weighted Price = 163.81

2nd Day Weighted Price = 136.45

3rd Day Weighted Price = 189.91

4th Day Weight Price = 149.25

Please advise me how what's wrong and how to use cumulate function via Pine script

regards , my friends !

Answer (score 0):

I think the loop has the problem , you have defined NewVol as integer inside the loop. It is float type.
try this , I have replaced the for loop with sum(source,length) , it will do the same task and its much efficient in pine script.

```
study("籌碼平均線 by Jason")

PriceDis = (close-(high+low)/2) * (close-(high+low)/2)

NewVol = PriceDis * volume
length_to_calculate_NewVol=input(3,"Input length to calculate cumulating NewVol")

TotalNewVol = sum(NewVol ,length_to_calculate_NewVol)

WeightedVol = NewVol / TotalNewVol

WeightedPrice = close * WeightedVol

plot(WeightedPrice)
```

Comment: wow , your code is clean and easy to understand , thanks bro !

Comment: the code is right , but the indicator doesn't work , haha , thanks !

Comment: are you getting any error ? I have update the code , Try with the updated code

Comment: Thanks updated ! The old one has no error too , but the indicator doesn't project anything.